# Proving the perpendicular distance from a point to a line using vectors (the harder algebraic way)

Tags: solution-verification, vectors

I want to prove that the distance from a point $P\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)$ to line $l$: $ax+by+c=0$ is given by $\frac{\left|ax_{0}+by_{0}+c\right|}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}$.

So I am stuck on $$\left|\text{perp}_lAP\right|=\left|\binom{x_0}{y_0+\frac{c}{b}}-\frac{-bx_0+ay_0+\frac{ac}{b}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\:\binom{-b}{a}\right|$$

Where $l$ is the vector parallel to the line,and $AP$ is a vector. See diagram/graph for context.

So I took the projection of $AP$ onto $l$, then found the perpendicular by proj+perp=l

And this should work right? I see no error, but just a very messy simplification.

I know the better way is to do instead, the projection from $PA$ onto $l$, which we know is perpendicular anyway.

But me doing |perp| = |$l$-proj| SHOULD also work right?How do I simplify it (especially turning $bx_0$ into $ax_0$)

Diagram:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4kka.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your method and calculations are not too complicated. But it is rather a small mistake that caused you grief.

[image]

If $M$ is the foot of the perpendicular on line $l$, you have not defined $\vec {AM}$ correctly.

$\displaystyle \frac{-bx_0+ay_0+\frac{ac}{b}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ is the magnitude of the projection of $\vec {AP}$ on line $l$ as you have taken dot product of $\vec {AP}$ with unit vector in direction of line $l$. Now if you are multiplying it by $(-b, a)$, that is wrong. It gives you a vector with different magnitude. To get to $\vec{AM}$, it should be multiplied by unit vector in direction of line $l$. So,

$\begin {aligned}
|\vec{MP}|&=\left|\binom{x_0}{y_0+\frac{c}{b}}-\frac{-bx_0+ay_0+\frac{ac}{b}}{a^2+b^2}\:\binom{-b}{a}\right| \\
& = \dfrac{1}{(a^2+b^2)} \left| (a^2+b^2)\binom{x_0}{y_0+\frac{c}{b}} + \left(-bx_0+ay_0+\frac{ac}{b}\right)\:\binom{b}{-a}\right| \\
&= \dfrac{1}{(a^2+b^2)} \left|\binom{a^2x_0 + ab y_0 + ac}{abx_0 + b^2y_0+bc}\right| \\
& = \dfrac{1}{(a^2+b^2)} \left| (ax_0 + by_0 + c) \binom{a}{b}\right| \\ 
&= \dfrac{\left|ax_0+by_0+c\right|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} 
\end{aligned}$

That's all.

Comment: Nicely done (+1). @user71207 You should accept this answer, instead.

Comment: @dxiv thank you for your compliments!

Comment: I see. So it was a silly mistake on my part. That is always most annoying

Answer (score 2):

Don't think there is a way to work it out completely "nicely" this way, but it can be made somewhat easier by making a couple of adjustments in the setup of the problem.

- A line proper cannot have $a$ and $b$ both $0$, so it can be assumed WLOG that $a^2+b^2=1$ by dividing the equation by $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Once the distance is proven to be $\mid ax_0+by_0+c\mid$ under this assumption, the substitutions can be reversed $a \to \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, $b \to \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, $c \to \frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ to recover the general result.
- With $a^2+b^2=1$, the reference point $\left(0,-\frac{c}{b}\right)$ can be chosen as $(-ca,-cb)$, instead, to preserve some of the symmetry and simplify the calculations.

With the above, the orthogonal component in the case $a^2+b^2=1$ becomes:

$$
T \;=\;\binom{x_0+ca}{y_0+cb}-\left(bx_0-ay_0\right)\binom{b}{-a}
$$

Then:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
|T|^2 &= \left(x_0+ca-b(bx_0-ay_0)\right)^2 + \left(y_0+cb+a(bx_0-ay_0)\right)^2
\\ &= x_0^2+2cax_0 + c^2a^2 - 2b(x_0+ca)(bx_0-ay_0)+b^2(bx_0-ay_0)^2
\\ &\;\;\;\; + y_0^2+2cby_0+c^2b^2 + 2a(y_0+cb)(bx_0-ay_0)+a^2(bx_0-ay_0)^2
\\ &= x_0^2+y_0^2+2c(ax_0+by_0)+c^2-2(bx_0+\cancel{bca}-ay_0-\cancel{acb})(bx_0-ay_0)+(bx_0-ay_0)^2
\\ &=x_0^2+y_0^2+2acx_0+2bcy_0+c^2-b^2x_0^2-a^2y_0^2+2abx_0y_0
\\ &= a^2x_0^2+b^2y_0^2+c^2 +2abx_0y_0+2acx_0+2bcy_0
\\ &= \left(ax_0+by_0+c\right)^2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you. So my method is completely valid and free of error, it just happens to be extremely complicated but will eventual proceed to the correct answer as per the other method.

Comment: Why can we assume WLOG that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1$?

Comment: @user71207 Because $a$ and $b$ cannot be both $0$, we can divide the equation by $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \ne 0$ and get the equivalent equation for the same line $a'x+b'y+c'=0$ where $a'=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, $b'=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, $c'=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, *and* $a'^{\,2}+b'^{\,2} = 1$.

Comment: Ahh I see, yes because it is generalised

Comment: @user71207 And to your first question, yes, this follows the same approach you took, only with those couple of "shortcuts" to make the calculations a bit less laborious.

Answer (score 1):

The points where $ax+by+c=0$ can be parametrized as
$$
\left(\frac{-bt-ac}{a^2+b^2},\frac{at-bc}{a^2+b^2}\right)\tag1
$$
The square of the distance from $(x_0,y_0)$ is then
$$
\begin{align}
&\left(x_0+\frac{bt+ac}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2+\left(y_0+\frac{-at+bc}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2\\[6pt]
&=\left(x_0^2+y_0^2\right)+\frac{2x_0(bt+ac)+2y_0(-at+bc)}{a^2+b^2}+\overbrace{\frac{(bt+ac)^2+(-at+bc)^2}{\left(a^2+b^2\right)^2}}^{\large\frac{t^2+c^2}{a^2+b^2}}\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac{\left(a^2+b^2\right)\left(x_0^2+y_0^2\right)+2c(ax_0+by_0)+2(bx_0-ay_0)t+c^2+t^2}{a^2+b^2}\tag{2b}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{\left(a^2+b^2\right)\left(x_0^2+y_0^2\right)+2c(ax_0+by_0)+c^2-(bx_0-ay_0)^2+(t+bx_0-ay_0)^2}{a^2+b^2}\tag{2c}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{a^2x_0^2+b^2y_0^2+2abx_0y_0+2c(ax_0+by_0)+c^2+(t+bx_0-ay_0)^2}{a^2+b^2}\tag{2d}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{(ax_0+by_0+c)^2+(t+bx_0-ay_0)^2}{a^2+b^2}\tag{2e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: expand the squares collecting the first, middle, and last parts
$\text{(2b)}$: put over a common denominator and collect powers of $t$
$\text{(2c)}$: complete the square in $t$
$\text{(2d)}$: expand $\left(a^2+b^2\right)\left(x_0^2+y_0^2\right)-(bx_0-ay_0)^2$
$\text{(2e)}$: collect $(ax_0+by_0+c)^2$

$\text{(2e)}$ is minimized when $(t+bx_0-ay_0)^2=0$ which gives the minimum distance to be
$$
\frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\tag3
$$